# Overriding parent controls enabledness

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, tablelayoutpanel

In WinForms when you set the parent control's `Enabled` property all of the child controls follow suit.

However, I would like to enable just a single child control to be always always enabled (regardless of parent state).

In my example, I have a bunch of controls in a table layout panel whose enabledness is bound to the check state of a checkbox (which happens to be a child control).

Is this possible?

I would rather not add bindings to all the sibling controls.

Perhaps there is a non-visual, secondary grouping container "control" / component around that supports binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible. Windows won't let you do it.

Rethink your layout, place the control you use now as a parent and that child control you need enabled on the same level in the super-parent (sorry for the term).

Comment: I dislike posting "you can't do it" answers, never popular.  +1 for calling it.

Comment: "Popular" was never my thing :).